# How to put ACL on customer grid's export to CSV, based on roles?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, permissions, acl

Trying to put **ACL on customer Grid's export to CSV** functionality based on user role.

Add following fode in my module's adminhtml.xml file acl section

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer translate="title" module="customer">
                        <children>
                            <export translate="title">
                                <title>Export to CSV</title>
                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            </export>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

### and Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php added the following code

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
----
if ($this->_admin_session_acl_custom->isAllowed('admin/customer/export')) {
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
}
```

ACL admin/customer/export is in the admin nsession allowed list but the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the following line of code in the `_prepareColumns` method:

```
if ($this->_admin_session_acl_custom->isAllowed('admin/customer/export')) {
```

by the following line of code:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/customer/export')) {
```